# In dust.js, what is the streaming interface?

Tags: template-engine, dust.js

I've been using dust.js with the Callback Interface, and I'm pretty comfortable with it. Now I want to learn more about the Streaming Interface.

I've been over the docs [here](http://akdubya.github.com/dustjs/) and [here](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/wiki/) and the concept escapes me.

I guess my question are:

1. What does a streaming template mean? To me it sounds like I can use it to set
   up an object that when data is pushed to, it will respond by
   rendering that data against a template.
2. In what cases would I use Streaming instead of the Callback
   Interface?
3. Are there any code samples that may help my learning?

Thanks!

Comment: what do u mean with streaming interface?

I think you are talking about the stream method of the dust object

Comment: @JAiro yes, by streaming interface, I'm referring to the dust.stream () method. In the [documentation](http://akdubya.github.com/dustjs/) it's called "The Streaming Interface". I don't understand how it's supposed to work. I don't understand the difference between it and dust.render().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in the callback interface, you can only use the rendered templates once dust is done rendering the whole template - by supplying a callback - which often inserts the rendered template into the DOM.

in the streaming interface, you have more control over pretty much every part of the rendering process: how rendered chunks are put into the output stream, when you want parts of the page to be rendered etc.

when you use the callback interface, the callback interface has an 'out' attribute that it always appends to, which it eventually provides to you as the second param in the callback you supply to it. in the streaming interface, when a newly processed chunk is available, it emits an event called 'data' and leaves it to you to deal with the data.

So, say you have a very big template you want rendered, you can break the template up into chunks, which, when complete, will emit a 'data' event, and define a handler for putting that chunk into the DOM. in other words, you don't have to wait for the whole rendering process to finish to start displaying things on your page.

This can be useful if for example, you want to render multiple pages of your app at once, but only want to display one page to the user - e.g. if you use jquerymobile - then you'd use the streaming interface to help get the first page to the user as fast as possible - while asynchronously rendering the rest. hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, it was very helpful. Do you know of any other dust documentation resources besides the two that I mentioned in the question?

Comment: Nope. Those two are pretty much it in terms of docs for dust. I went through the code to understand more. I could do a write up on my blog. Anything in particular you need explained?

Comment: I am very interested in an example of generating several chunks and then stream them into the template. I am thinking of a large list of items. I guess streaming could be used perfectly for that but maybe I am wrong?

Comment: I think its a perfect use case for streaming. I don't have an with me, but I'll see if i can cook one up for you later.

Comment: @asyraf9, Please provide an example of the streaming interface. Here is what i tried http://jsfiddle.net/yXx5L/5/. I thought the 'data' event would be called on every iteration of the array, but it was not like that. How to mark a portion of a big template as a chunk, so that once it get rendered the 'data' callback will be called?